# Unable to see Mbean in browser but able to see it in Jconsole

Tags: java, prometheus, jmx, mbeans, jmx-exporter

I trying to use JMX Export to export some custom variables via Mbean. I am able to see the Mbean in jconsole but those attributes are not available in localhost:port\metrics. Tried whitelisting object name, changing patterns in rules but nothing seems to work.

Not sure if bean is exposed properly :/

```
package com.test;
public interface ApplicationInfoMXBean {
    public String getEnv();
}

package com.test;
public class ApplicationInfoImp implements ApplicationInfoMXBean{
    @Override
    public String getEnv() {
        return "XX";       
}

Bean declaration:

MBeanServer mbeanServer=ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ApplicationInfoMXBean appInfoObj=new ApplicationInfoImp();
ObjectName objName=new ObjectName("com.test:type=basic,name=ApplicationInfoImp");
mbeanServer.registerMBean(appInfoObj, objName); 

config.yaml
rules:
- pattern: ".*"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Prometheus JMX exporter doesn't export MBean String attributes since these aren't really metrics.